# Listening to a service property change in an EmberJs Octane Component

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am wondering how on Emberjs Octane to fire a function in a component after a service property changes.  Here is an example of how I did it before octane.

child-component.js before Octane

```
import Component from '@ember/component';
import {inject as service} from '@ember/service';
import {computed, observer} from '@ember/object';
import { isEmpty } from '@ember/utils';
import { on } from '@ember/object/evented';
export default Component.extend({

userAccount: service(),
childNavigation: service(),

whenUserChanges: on('init', observer( 'userAccount.user', 'childNavigation.{activeIgdiMeasure,currentChild}', function () {

        this.getChildItems();
    }))
})
```

Observers aren't recommended and @tracked isn't working on a service so I am not sure how to convert the whenUserChanges function to Octane.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow! `@tracked` does work on a service. Please post all of the relevant code so we can debug. Even better, post a reproduction.

Answer (score 0):

@tracked by default does not observe deep changes of an object , so you need to use spread operator `obj = {...obj}` to tell to tracked that the obj has changed or you can use  [ember-deep-tracked](https://github.com/NullVoxPopuli/ember-deep-tracked), and to call the getChildItems by observing user.account.status you can use rendering hooks provided by 
[ember-render-modifiers](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-render-modifiers)  , like `did-insert` at template level,  for example the following code ,

```
// services/user.js
import Service from '@ember/service';
import {tracked} from '@glimmer/tracking';
import {action} from '@ember/object';

export default class UserService extends Service {
  @tracked account;
  @tracked items=[];

  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);

    this.account = {
      name: 'myname1',
      status: 'active',
    };
  }

  @action
  changeStatus(status) {
    this.account.status = status;
    this.account = {...this.account}
  }

 @action
  getChildItems() {
      const itemsFromApi = [1,2,3,4,5]
     this.items = [...itemsFromApi];
  }
}

// components/navbar.js
import Component from '@glimmer/component';
import {inject as service } from '@ember/service';
export default class NavbarComponent extends Component {

  @service user;
}



{{!-- components/navbar.hbs --}}
Status:{{this.user.account.status}}

<button type="button" {{on 'click' (fn this.user.changeStatus
  (if (eq this.user.account.status 'active') 'notActive' 'active'))}}>
  Change status
</button>


{{#if (eq this.user.account.status 'active')}}

  <ul {{did-insert this.user.getChildItems}}>
    {{#each this.user.items as |item|}}
      <li>{{item}}</li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
{{/if}}




{{!-- templates/application.hbs --}}
{{page-title "Testproject"}}

<Navbar/>

{{outlet}}
```